# Remaining Hour Per day for difference between two timestamp using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am working on a log data where i had to find the usage of a software on a daily basis . for instance if the log shows for a user : start time 04/01/2019 9:15 AM End Time 04/03/2019 12:00 PM. If i take a difference between these two dates then i will get the data usage for the span not for a particular day. is there a way where i can get the data usage per day until the end date.

Data would be of similar form shown below

[image]

and here is what i am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since, you don't provide some origin data, I create some fake data myself. Also I not sure whether you mean to compare `Start date` with `End date` from your description. If I misunderstand you, please post comment below.

```
In [10]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [11]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [12]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2], "Start":[20190302, 20190401], "End": [20190304, 20190402]})                                                                                                                                           

In [13]: df1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[13]: 
   A     Start       End
0  1  20190302  20190304
1  2  20190401  20190402

In [14]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.repeat((df1.End - df1.Start > 1) + 1, axis=0), columns=df1.columns)                                                                                                                                    

In [15]: df2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[15]: 
   A     Start       End
0  1  20190302  20190304
1  1  20190302  20190304
2  2  20190401  20190402
```

If you need to compare your actually date, you may want to use something like `datetime` lib to do that. Form example:

```
In [28]: import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [29]: dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("11/30/2018 17:13", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")                                                                                                                                                               

In [30]: dt1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[30]: datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 17, 13)

In [31]: dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("11/29/2018 17:13", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")                                                                                                                                                               

In [32]: dt3 = datetime.datetime.strptime("11/28/2018 17:13", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")                                                                                                                                                               

In [33]: dt1 - dt2                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[33]: datetime.timedelta(days=1)

In [34]: (dt1 - dt2).days                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[34]: 1

In [35]: (dt1 - dt3).days                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[35]: 2
```

Comment: I was working on a log data where i had to find the usage of a software on a daily basis . for instance if the log shows for a user : start time 04/01/2019 9:15 AM End Time 04/03/2019 12:00 PM. If i take a difference between these two dates then i will get the data usage for the span not for a particular day. is there a way where i can get the data usage per day until the end date. please let me know if you need any further clarification. Thanks for the help

Comment: Seems your question is far away from your comment! Anyway, You probably want to try using ELK.